# What is the best way to verify an OS X user password using the Python standard library?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, passwords

I am writing a script that prompts the logged in user for their password using CocoaDialog in order to initiate FileVault 2 encryption.

Ideally, I'd like to verify that the password is correct, but I haven't found a good way to do so. I tried spawning /usr/libexec/chkpasswd via the subprocess module, but it seems to hit return before I can pass the password to stdin. (I just get "Sorry", which is the stdout for a wrong password.)

I briefly looked at pexpect, but I'd like to do this without third party tools in order to keep deployment simple.

All Macs would be running OS X 10.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look around digs up this: [the Darwin source for PAM authentication in chkpasswd](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-496/chkpasswd.tproj/pam_passwd.c). It looks like chkpasswd is using its own sub-TTY to get your password:

```
/* Initialize PAM. */
pamc.conv = &openpam_ttyconv;
pam_start(progname, uname, &pamc, &pamh);

printf("Checking password for %s.\n", uname);
```

[and then more PAM specific code to see if the password works out.]

This is good for security, but bad for you: there won't be any way you can use I/O redirection to send over the password. Depending on how pexpect works, *it* might even not be able to do it: it might keep sending input to the TTY in which chkpasswd is running rather than to the sub-terminal. I don't know enough about the wiring of each of those components to give a guess without testing it out.

I know this doesn't really solve your question, but I thought it would be worth noting.

Comment: I'll mark this as a solution, because it got me thinking in the right direction. I ended up reusing code from a PAM authentication module (http://atlee.ca/software/pam/) in my script.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you got a solution!